# How i add Event to default calendar in iOS Module through Titanium?

Tags: titanium, titanium-modules

I want to make iOS Module with Titanium appcelerator. I have connected app.js file to xCode. every this is working fine.
I can send data and get response. But when I write code for add Event in default Calendar then this is crashed

```
EKEventStore *eventStore1 = [[EKEventStore alloc] init];
EKEvent *event  = [EKEvent eventWithEventStore:eventStore1];
event.title     = @"EVENT TITLE  4";
event.notes     = @"NOtes";
event.startDate = [[NSDate alloc] init];
event.endDate   = [[NSDate alloc] initWithTimeInterval:600 sinceDate:event.startDate];

[event setCalendar:[eventStore1 defaultCalendarForNewEvents]];
NSError *err;
[eventStore1 saveEvent:event span:EKSpanThisEvent error:&err];
NSLog(@" Error is %@",err);
```

How I solve this problem? 
this is Error Msg

```
output = run.run(args,False,False,o)
[DEBUG] File "/Users/mac03/Library/Application Support/Titanium/mobilesdk/osx/2.0.2.GA/iphone/run.py", line 41, in run
[DEBUG] sys.exit(rc)
[DEBUG] SystemExit: 65
[ERROR] Build Failed. See: /var/folders/5s/3wmzx34548d9jnj7z7v1ylc40000gn/T/mLmdFS2ti/test/build/iphone/build/build.log
mac03:test mac03$ titanium run
```

I have add Eventkit.framework and also import.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to change your module.xconfig file to include this line.

```
OTHER_LDFLAGS=$(inherited) -framework EventKit
```

This informs the application to build the EventKit framework into the main binary, it is not enough just to include it in your modules XCode project. [Check this part of the docs for more information.](http://docs.appcelerator.com/titanium/2.1/index.html#!/guide/iOS_Module_Development_Guide-section-29004946_iOSModuleDevelopmentGuide-AddingSpecialCompilerDirectives)